# How to call the getId() function on an instantiated resource Model

Tags: magento2

this is how i used to get an Id from a model:

```
 /** @var \Top\ExampleModule\Model\example $object */

 $object = $this->modelFactory->create()->load(1,'custom_field');

$object->getId()
```

I am aware that the load method of the model will be deprecated.

I understand that the correct way to load is to use the **Resource Model**. My issue however is that the resourceModel does not have  **getData()** or **getId()** methods.

How then can I get the Id of the instantiated model if there is no
$this->getId() method.

This is how I now call it:

```
/** @var \Top\ExampleModule\Model\example $object */
$model = $this->modelFactory->create();
$object =  $this->viewResource->load($model, $id,'custom_field');

$object->getId()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading model data using `$model->load(1, 'custom_field')` and `$modelResource->load($model, 1, 'custom_field')` has the same effect, except that `$model->load()` will trigger the `model_load_before` and `model_load_after` events.

So basically the code you have written will work.

```
/** @var \Top\ExampleModule\Model\example $object */
$model = $this->modelFactory->create();

// here $id is null, because there are no data populated to the model
$id = $model->getId();

// this will populate the $model with data
$this->viewResource->load($model, $id,'custom_field');

// here $id is set, because the data has been populated to the model by the resource model
$id = $model->getId();
```

Comment: that is brilliant. i now understand. thanks Rendy

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that the correct way to load is to use the Resource Model

That's wrong. The correct way is to use the service contracts, which are implemented with repository interfaces/classes.

For example, to load a product by SKU or ID, you would use `Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface` with methods `get()` and `getById()`.

To load one or more products by any other attribute, you would use its method `getList()`.

Comment: Is that the only correct way nowadays? Even if I don't want to expose my entity due be module's internal use only? Example: I need to save an external shipping label link once Magento only accept image. It gonna be used only when user click print shipping label in admin.

Comment: You can always opt for a different structure in your own module, but this is still the recommended way: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-contracts.html